# K&R excersize 1-17

Tags: c

> Exercise 1-17. Write a program to print all input lines that are
> longer than 80 characters.

I wrote this code for the exercise :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    int line[80];

    while (c != EOF)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 80 && (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i)
        {
            if (c == '\n')
                i = 0;
            else
                line[i] = c;
        }

        if (c != EOF)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i)
                putchar(line[i]);
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                putchar(c);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I give it an input, it also prints lines that have 80 characters, rather than just those with more than 8 characters(I checked the character count in each line with vim). What's causing it to? How do I fix it.

Edit :

An example: I put this text in a file called 'j'.

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

vim says that the first line is 99 characters long, the second 49, the third 79 and the last line is 89 characters long.
My program is compiled into a file named 'a.out'.

When I run the command `cat j | ./a.out` I expect only for the last and first line to be printed but the output I get is this:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The third line which has 79 characters is printed too whereas I want only lines with more than 80 characters to be printed, not those that are 80 characters long or shorter than that.

Comment: Can you add a paragraph about how you think your program works?

Comment: You should start with looking at compiler warnings. `while (c != EOF)` You are using `c` without initialization when you first come here. If your compiler doesn't warn you, you should increase warning leve. For GCC add options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Do you consider the newline character as part of the character count?

Comment: Please add some sample input data together with your output and expected output.

Comment: @Bob__ Perhaps more importantly, if you are on Windows: Do you consider the *carriage return* as part of the character count?

Comment: Maybe you should use some input that allows you distinguishing where the data comes from. With all the same characters it is hard to tell if that is some garbage from previous lines or new data.

Comment: With your added data, it seems that only with len 79 you get incorrect output. That also hints towards handling ´\n` or `\r`  might need some more attention. You should run your program in a debugger and check what happens in that line.

Comment: I suggest rewriting your code so that there is only one `getchar()` call (in a loop) and therefore only one `EOF` check.  Determine based on the character read and the number already buffered, if any, what action to take.  This will be cleaner and probably easier to reason about.  My own version would be shorter, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. `while (c != EOF)` invokes undefined behavior as `c` is not initialized
2. line has wrong type. it should be `char`
3. I added null character terminator to use `line` as string (to show how to archive it)
4. You need to print the remaining part of the line even if it longer than 80 characters.

```
#define MAXLINE 80

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    size_t i;
    char line[MAXLINE + 1];

    do{
        for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE && ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) && c!= '\n'; i++)
        {
            line[i] = c;
        }
        if(i == MAXLINE)
        {
            line[i] = 0;
            printf("%s", line);
            if(c != '\n' && c!= EOF) while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') putc(c, stdout);
            putc('\n', stdout);
        }
    }while(c != EOF);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add a terminator to the buffer if you use an explicit precision when you print it: `printf("%.80s", line)`.  Not that it matters much one way or the other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was showing how to create C string. Bare in mind level of the question

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions by [Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh), in the comment section, the OP should follow:

> [...] `while (c != EOF)` You are using c without initialization when you first come here. [...]

> Maybe you should use some input that allows you distinguishing where the data comes from. With all the same characters it is hard to tell if that is some garbage from previous lines or new data.

Let's try a lower limit of, say, **4** characters, instead of 80 and an input like the following:

```
4321
123
abcdef
98
EDCBA
12
abc
```

The expected output should be

```
abcdef
EDCBA
```

The posted<sup>1</sup> code would output something different:

```
4321
1abcdef
9EDCBA
1abc
```

We can see the spurious characters in the last lines and that the first line, which has exactly the same number of characters as the limit, is outputted too.

Let's look closely to the first `for` loop, its condition and how it resets and updates the `i` variable.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 80 && (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i)
{ //            ^^^^^^                            ^^^
     if (c == '\n')
         i = 0;       // <-- After this, i is immediately incremented
     else
         line[i] = c;
}
```

When a line with less than 80 characters is encountered, the *following* line is copied in the array starting from index **1**, not zero, because the increment of `i` is performed *before* the condition of the loop is evaluated.

Besides, the condition `i < 80` makes the first loop stop when, well, `i` is *equal* to 80 (4 in my modified example).

We can see that the offending line in OP's output has *exactly* 80 `1` characters, while the corresponding one in the input has 79 of them.

---

I won't post a solution, but let me quote [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) comment:

> I suggest rewriting your code so that there is only one `getchar()` call (in a loop) and therefore only one `EOF` check. Determine based on the character read and the number already buffered, if any, what action to take.

---

<sup>1) Well, once the magic number is adjusted and `c` initialized: https://godbolt.org/z/vdonxeMoo</sup>